# auto-pst-pdf and TeXstudio under MacTeX

Tags: texstudio, mactex, texshop, auto-pst-pdf

I use `pdflatex` to compile source files that contain EPS figures as well as PSTricks. My standard way of handling this is to use `auto-pst-pdf`. I have been using TeXstudio to compile files under Windows with no problem. Recently, I have tried the same under MacTeX 2013 with TeXstudio 2.6.4 with no success and the error message

> sh: latex: command not found.

I know that `auto-pst-pdf` runs `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` first, but I do not understand why running `latex` runs into trouble.

By the way, TeXShop runs the file with no problem.

Minimal Example: This code runs fine under windows (with MikTeX) when I use Winedt or Texstudio. It also runs fine with MacTex if I use Texshop, but gives me errors if I run it with texstudio on Mac. It returns a pdf file that instead of the figure has a blank square in it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
This is a test. The following figure should be processed OK when PdfLaTeX is run.

\bigskip

\includegraphics[width=5in]{fig4.eps}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you set the paths correctly for TeXStudio?  Can it compile anything?

Comment: @Alan Munn. The path is OK. In fact it compiles the file but figures are substituted by blank squares. My remote guess: auto-pst-pdf internally calls latex, but the path by which it calls latex is not correct?

Comment: Can you try doing `which latex` in a Terminal window?

Comment: @egreg  which latex gives /usr/texbin/latex .

Comment: @per Can you add a minimal example?

Comment: @egreg, please see the edited question for a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose your problem, try this with `pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex`.

```
% this input file name is filename.tex
% compile it with pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex

\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{temporary.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{example-image-a.eps}}
\psset{xunit=\wd\IBox,yunit=\ht\IBox}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](1,1)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx,pgffor}
\edef\AutoRotateOff{-dAutoRotatePages=/None}

\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,ps2pdf \AutoRotateOff/ps}{\immediate\write18{\compiler\space temporary.\ext}}

\begin{document}
This is a test. The following figure should be processed OK when PdfLaTeX is run.

\bigskip

\includegraphics{temporary.pdf}% extension is not necessary
\end{document}
```

If you can get the following, there is a problem with your editor.

[image]

Comment: Tried this at the command prompt, works fine with the expected result. Tried with Texshop, again works fine. Tried with texstudio, get the following error messages:   sh: latex: command not found

sh: dvips: command not found

sh: ps2pdf: command not found

Process exited normally

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've also installed the [pdfcrop](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop) package. It installs a small Perl script to crop the generated PDF to its bounding box size, so that it can be included in your main LaTeX document.

Comment: pdfcrop is installed. That is why Texsop compiles the example with no problem.

Comment: In the compilation command setting for TeXstudio (where you have "`latex ...`", have you enabled the option `-shell-escape`?

Comment: -shell-escape option is already there.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
```

Comment: tried, same result. I think the error is in the latex+dvips+ps2pdf step, and most probably in the latex step of it.

Comment: then the paths for the TeX/LaTeX binaries are not correct set in TeXstudio